# React-native sound delay issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

This is just general question. I want to make drums-like app but i have sound delay. Maybe someone tried some other package(s) and did some magic, I used react-native-sound and react-native-video since they are most popular and not outdated like others. This is code sample:

```
new Sound(`${filename}.mp3`, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
  if (error) {
    return;
  } else {
    audio.play(() => {
      audio.release();
    });
  }
});
```

There are other libraries, maybe outdated, but i am looking for any input to make it better, we did handler with onPressIn to make it slightly faster but still big delay:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPressIn={handleOpenPress}>
```

If this fails I will try to make another library, but I fear it will have the same delay. For some reason this repo works very fast: https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-drum-kit. I used same code and made even a list with prepared sounds to be used like soundList[i++ % 10].play() but still no effect.